# LaTeX Beamer - Temporarily increase font size of an item when using "itemize"

Tags: beamer, presentations

Does someone know how I can have larger fonts for an item during presentation. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item A
            \pause
            \item item B
            \pause
            \item item C
            \pause
            \item item D
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So, during the presentation I would like to go through each of the four items (A to D) one by one as follows: First I would like only item A to appear while items B to D should be faded (gray). then I would like to show item B with a slightly enlarged font while items A, C and D are faded. Then I would like to show item C with a slightly enlarged font while items A, B and D are faded, and the font for item B should be the original font. Finally i would like to show item D with a slightly enlarged font with all the other items faded.

Is there a way of achieving this in beamer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}, dynamic}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{size=\huge}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
    Item in default size \huge foo \normalsize

    \begin{itemize}[<+|alert@+>]
        \item item A
        \item item B
        \item item C
        \item item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about it, but it requires to redefine `alert` size. I don't find another way to put something in the options of `itemize` to have the requested behavior. Someone have an idea?

Comment: use `\setbeamerfont` inside the frame, define your own frame style, redefine `\itemize`, ...

Comment: Thanks again, Lopezo. your solution adequately addresses my problem

Comment: Then can you validate the solution that works for you?

Comment: I think it is better to define a custom action for that `\newenvironment{bigenv}{\only{\Large}}{}` which can then be used like this `\begin{itemize}[<+|big@+>]`. So you don't have to mess with `alert`

Answer (score 3):

This code does not change the size of the police but do the other tricks and I think this is what you look for.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}, dynamic}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+>]
            \item item A
            \item item B
            \item item C
            \item item D
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the `\Large` size but I am not sure it is the optimal LaTeX code but it works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}, dynamic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+> \only<1>{\Large}item A
        \item<+> \only<2>{\Large}item B
        \item<+> \only<3>{\Large}item C
        \item<+> \only<4>{\Large}item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Lopezo. I think it would be nice to be able to achieve the font enlargement as well.

Comment: I edit my answer with the enlargement.

Comment: @Lopezo I think it would make more sense to use `\only` instead of `\temporal` as you don't need the replacement functionality of `\temporal`.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, indeed, it's better. I update the post.